How do I make a \newcommand generate \emph to be processed?
Trying to create a \newcommand for indicating semantic information in a bulleted list along lines of
\begin{itemize}
    \qkey{foo {bar baz} quux}
\end{itemize}

my initial thought was to create a sublist with the bracketed substring as the parent \item. As a simpler start, I tried to emphasize the portion instead, where the \qkey above becomes
\item foo \emph{bar baz} quux

If I decide later that, say, bold would look better, I’d need change to \textbf in only one place.
I got as far as the code below to simply replace the first inner brace with \emph.
\edef\lbracetoken{\string{}%

\newcommand{\qkey}[1]{%
    \StrSubstitute{\detokenize{#1}}{\lbracetoken}{\string\emph\lbracetoken}[\result]%
    \typeout{Substitution result: \result}%
    \item \scantokens{\result}%
}

The log output looks correct, but the bullets render in the document as shown below. (Where do the strange quote marks come from?)
Substitution result: foo \emph{bar baz} quux
Substitution result: plain text without braces
Substitution result: \emph{start} and more text

Minimal example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\edef\lbracetoken{\string{}%
\newcommand{\qkey}[1]{%
    \StrSubstitute{\detokenize{#1}}{\lbracetoken}{\string\emph\lbracetoken}[\result]%
    \typeout{Substitution result: \result}%
    \item \scantokens{\result}% Pass the expanded result to \item
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \qkey{foo {bar baz} quux}
    \qkey{plain text without braces}
    \qkey{{start} and more text}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}

Output:


welcome! can you provide a complete minimal example we can compile to produce the output you show? but, in general, this can't work because your substitute has incorrect category codes. (I think.) but also you are trying to implement a highly unusual syntax and it isn't obvious what the motivation for this is. \qkey sord \highlight{bold} more would be a more natural syntax. failing that, choosing something other than characters used as begin/end group tokens would make your life easier ;).

you could use expl3 regular expressions, but that approach is very slow, so think carefully about whether you really want to pay that price. if this is for small amounts of text, it should be fine, but you wouldn't want to mark up large chunks of a book with it or something. then you could just replace the first begin-group-token with an extra token followed by itself to get \emph{.

Are you sure you want to do this? It's possible in simple cases but horribly fragile and in incompatible with tex syntax. Why not use a command form?

@cfr Thank you for the suggestions. I added an MWE and an image of the output document. Your point about a separate command tells me I made the first step too simple — so much that it cut against the grain.

@DavidCarlisle The admonition implied in an expert’s question is noted. To answer: No, I’m clearly not sure. I wanted to leave a free hand for later in case I want to use a more elaborate structure (as in the nested lists mentioned in my question), but my first approach was not a natural fit.

You could use a brace-delimited auxiliary macro. Note that this leaves LaTeX syntax-realm and enters plain TeX syntax. But with that this is rather simple and fast.
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\qkey[1]{\item\qkeyAux#1{}}
\def\qkeyAux#1#{#1\emph}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \qkey{foo {bar baz} quux}
  \qkey{plain text without braces}
  \qkey{{start} and more text}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}


Keep in mind that this goes horribly wrong for input like \qkey{foo \textbf{bar} {emphasised} baz}.
